# How to save figures of 4D matrix in a subfolders in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, subdirectory, figure, save-as

I have a 4D matrix with a size of `3x600x600x28` and want to save all the images in a 3D matrix `(600X600x28)` which contains 28 images in subfolders that correspond with the first index of the matrix. It means I need 3 main folders which each of them contains 28 images.

The question is that how can I save the first 28 images in the folder which is named `1` and the second 28 images in folder `2` and so on...

I stuck at the last line of the code saveas...

Here is my try:

```
clc;
clear;

n=3;
A = randi([1 255],n,600,600,28);
for i=1:n
mkdir('Output_image',num2str(i));
    for j=1:28
        h=figure;    
        p = pcolor(A(i,:,:,j));
        p.EdgeColor='none';
        set(gca,'visible','off')
        colormap('jet');
        axis equal;
        title 'Von Mises Stress';
        saveas(h,sprintf('Output_image/%i/FIG%d.jpg',j));
     end  
end
```

Comment: What's the problem? You haven't asked a question (?)... please be specific and [edit] your question to highlight where you're actually stuck - at the minute you have a goal and some code, we know little else

Comment: The last line should just be `saveas(h,sprintf('Output_image/%d/FIG%d.jpg',i,j))` I think? You need the two numbers as inputs for your two `%` placeholders I'm sprintf